# make compiler copy function's code inside a other function passed as argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, obfuscation, compiler-optimization

My question is very specific, i want force compiler to take the code of a funtion and copy it inside a another one, like inline or __forceinline keywords can do, but i want pass the function i want to copy in the other funtion, as an argument. Here is a simple example.

```
using pFunc = void(*)();
void func_1() { /*some code*/ }
void func_2(pFunc function) { /*some code*/ } //after compile i want this funtion takes no argument and copy the func_1 inside this.
int main()
{
   func_2(func_1);
}
```

so with this example the compiler will pass the pointer of func_1 as argunent to func_2, as expected.
I tried add inline keyword for func_1 and also tried to pass the argument of func_2 as reference, but compiler didn't copied the func_1 inside func_2.
Any idea how can i do that?

I use the compiler of visual studio(msvc) with toolset 2017(v141).
My project platform is x64.

Comment: **Why do you want this?** Why can't you *generate* C or C++ code (or assembly code, or use `asm` keyword) with some script (or your own software tool)?

Comment: Why would you need to copy the code? Sounds like a xy-problem  for me.

Comment: So you want the compiler to do constant-propagation into a clone of `void func_2(pFunc f){ f(); }`?  Like what GCC might do with `__attribute__((noinline))` but not `noclone`?  MSVC might not be willing to do that optimization, instead preferring to just inline func_2 to a `call func_1`.  If you want to force it to make clunky asm that duplicates `func_1` unnecessarily, you could use a template, taking the function pointer as a template arg, so you can instantiate `func_2<func1>` as a stand-alone non-inline function if you really want.  (Perhaps with `_declspec(noinline)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i want do this because i need make it harder for hackers to hack my application. How asm code can help here? Do you have any example?

Comment: Ehr... C++ isn't python, C++ is compiled (source code isn't shipped to hackers). That's already pretty hard to reverse engineer (not impossible though). If you want to make it really hard you should encrypt the resulting binaray (in part) and have it self decrypt before execution (and no I don't know how to that).

Comment: Or are you implying you have a function that does some security checking and you don't want to have that function in one place? So that changing a branch in one place will disable all the checks in the other places? If so this might be one of those exceptions where you put the check in a macro (yes I don't like them) and then put that macro in various places in the code where it will expand.

Comment: @PeterCordes can you write a simple c++ code? I don't understand why i should use __declspec(noinline) when i want to force compiler put the code inline...

Comment: @Giannis: What will happen if somone hacked (or reverse-engineered using [Binsec](https://binsec.github.io/)...) your executable? How many samples did you sold? In what country do you code, or do you sell your application?

Comment: @PepijnKramer python can compiled also. However even compiled code can be decompiled and there are public tools can generate c++ pseudocode that will show a code very close to original one. But if compiler do a lot optimizations like that i try to make, the pseudocode will be way different than original code. Also it will be impossible to simpy hook the funtion and change the funtion pointer to a funtion that hacker created

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is not use C++ but rather use assembly.  Self-modifying code is slightly trickier on modern operating systems, because the executable memory is often tagged as not modifiable.  So your assembly code will have to request permissions to modify the executable memory region.

Comment: I think the last point, where hooking only one function will compromise security is the one to be worried about not dissassembly. So I can see why you want to duplicate code so you have multiple hooking points. But then copying the exact same function wouldn't confuse a hacker too much either (look for repeats in assembly). And probably you should do some runtime checks to check your code hasn't been modified before it runs. In memory it is usually in read-only memory segments anyway

Comment: @Eljay i don't want modify code at runtime and i don't want use asm if is unnecessary. I ask if is possible tell compiler do this optimization while it compile the code

Comment: No you can't make the compiler generate "more secure code". The compiler optimizations are for speed or memory use. It will not inject anything to make code harder to hack. Your code must be worth a lot if you need to go through the effort of making it hack-proof. Like any security it will not be unbreakable, it just should resist tampering for long enough to be worth your while

Comment: Example of a large C code base with `asm` is the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/)

Comment: @PepijnKramer compiler itself will not make it more secure i know. However you can run funtions in compile time (like strings/data encryption) and can make optimizations that will force in functions debug checks or trash code that will make harder to reverse code or invalid instructions that will make analyze tools failed

Comment: @PepijnKramer: You can't make the compiler generate "more secure code" in general, but you can do this weird clone thing the querent asked for fairly easily with a `_declspec(noinline)` template.  Unfortunately the question was closed before I finished writing a working answer for GCC/clang/MSVC.  For now I edited it into the question just so it's somewhere (and as a proof that this is answerable) before I sleep.

Comment: BTW, I don't think this looks like much of an obfuscation technique.  I only answered as an exercise in making a compiler spit out the asm I wanted it to.  Obviously it only works for compile-time-constant function pointers; other commenters have been discussing self-modifying code and scripting languages.  If you wanted this for non-const function pointer args to func_1, you're completely out of luck in a language like C++ that's designed for strictly ahead-of-time compilation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sometimes questions get closed too soon. And yes there is only so much you can do from within C++

Comment: @PepijnKramer: yup, part of why I replied to a comment was to ping someone else who might cast a reopen vote.  If that was you, thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can make compiler generate more secure code. Only if think that you can force compiler call your encryption for texts(like other encryption keys) and decrypt them only when you need it, will make in general a more secure program. It is work of compiler to call the encryption part when it compile the code, no need use external tools

Comment: @Eljay: I didn't think this was asking about self-modifying code, only about cases like shown where the arg to `func_2` is a compile-time constant (so could be a template param).  I have an answer ready to post, if you wouldn't mind reopening.

Comment: @PeterCordes i didn't closed the post, i guess it is because people dislike the post and they not tell me what is wrong so i can fix it. Maybe my mistake was i asked this security/anti-reversing based question at a code-engineering based forum?

Comment: @Giannis: IDK why so many people misinterpreted it as wanting run-time inlining / function-creation.  The title clearly said you wanted the *compiler* to do this.  It's a weird non-obvious thing to want, though, and your question didn't mention any motivation for it.  That would have helped.  Some people may have assumed you couldn't possibly have wanted what it sounded like you were describing, and assumed an X-Y problem.  Or aren't used to thinking of compilers as tools to create machine code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Re: code being in read-only pages.  Yes, but a debugger can use `ptrace` or equivalent debug APIs to get the kernel to modify pages, possibly triggering a copy-on-write.  Similar to how runtime fixups (text relocations) can be applied during dynamic linking, although that's from inside the same process.  An executable's pages being read-only by default is basically zero obstacle for a local user messing with a program running under their account.  Or using a root / admin account to debug any process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use a noinline template function to get the asm you want

So you want the compiler to do constant-propagation into a clone of `void func_2(pFunc f){ f(); }`?  Like what GCC might do with `__attribute__((noinline))` but not `noclone`?

For example,

```
using pFunc = void(*)();
int sink, sink2;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define NOINLINE _declspec(noinline)
#else
#define NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline)) // noclone and/or noipa
#endif

__attribute__((always_inline))  // without this, gcc chooses to clone .constprop.0 with just a jmp func_2
void func_1() { sink = 1; sink2 = 2; }
NOINLINE static void func_2(pFunc function) {  function(); }

int main()
{
   func_2(func_1);
}
```

produces, with GCC11.3 -O2 or higher, or `-O1 -fipa-cp`, [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJmpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMVxxdpgOqUIETMQE6T5%2BXLaY9rkM1bUE%2BWGR0bG2NXUNmc0KQ93BvUX9pQCUtqhexMjsHF7JRgDU8QBiXgzIWyYAzAAiWwBuqHjoEABUcxBzp1YaAILBBFubANakP2CvzMrxMH3MJzwVCwVC2AH0ALJCNxwgBq2AASmD3hCYVMtqEAPIASVCAVJ2HhWGQtAU8QqEAYNwYtCmL3BZhOeJCW3eAQA6u8AJpCOGk8mhSlbAD09y292l2IhrSUSs53MwBJJZIp8LhTAIBGIeAiXgImDhcKgTOCrJCczmMulWyZ3yZNIEmpILpu8SYAIA7pr7gHDAQ5QQEElNUQtggmPF6Qw1VzMDQeXzBSKxTrJVs9QajSazRarRAxKGAJ4KOG2tnsnGc1xQpUfTPC0Xi3XS50BwhRs1bSN4BQA4DII7IKPRhRD1BbD08gB0aAY43ixFQ8SXGi2fcjW20G2%2BTEPLHiWyoB2QcJBH2ut0v17hXGexwA7BZAQxfsdzlsuFeb9gT/C4QROL8THfM5sSJLs83GA08COB90CfQ5bwgPZr3QyoBEdKCv1w9pniAqCYPBD4vi2FgmGCUjwU/bF81wzCrwwrgXggpVoI4BZaE4ABWXg/A4LRSFQTg3GsawfiWFZNQhHhSAITQ%2BIWX4QBOSQly4d8AE5BMEk4zAANkkUyNEkAAOZoBI4SQRLUiTOF4BQQA0FS1IWOBYBgRAUFQc86GichKDQYL6BiYAuC4E4%2BDoc1iHciAImciJglqStOGUiK2EEQkWWysTeCwWijHEErSHwYgKkcS5MHcqrMFUCoSxy3gvlaZzWQiYgso8LBnKLFgOoWKgDGABRUTwTAA0JJMOpkQQRDEdgpGW%2BQlDUZzdDiAwjBQGTLH0E13MgBYt3aJqAFpCROLYbpoP0buQeI3NaOrUhcBh3E8Rp/F%2BnpCmKLIkhSAQRiaBJwfaYG%2BhKFo2iqCYob0co8I6CZ4ZmRHEOGf7RkGLocdBzjFmWVY9CNTA1h4fihKcqrJI4VRrNMm7zK2ccjlipcHogaTLGsAFcEIb0lIBDxIuiY5OTMOZeFUkqHVITSTKXGz31i7SNDMDRTK4dn9E4RzSFGwTPNE8SWbcjyvJV0hfICiL4hCsgKAgV33ZQA6YskDRPJoWgkpStKqoy5hiGK3KgvyghCtoYrxLKwxgEqlO8FqyoGqa8SWra80lq6%2BzxN6/ro8GtZxJGsa%2BEm6bZvmxbuF4fgVtEcQNvbraVHUKrdHiv2juFk7evO54JPia7ODuk4PuR5wIFcNHmkCKYQdmGGclSVft4hhhSa3jH2k6AmMmhk%2BUZJjeEfR1HCcv7Hb9xiQFgUeSqeaGm6b4k2OGEqQa2vAWZsw5lzGkacAI6Q0DuLYgtjo2C2GLIgxA5YnGaFsaWbsoroJOIrB2WhVYIEwEwLAMRJ72TNhbK2zlba2HtsrIhGktJmE1tZbWcUA760Nsbey88gF0NcoQv%2BzsIBIG9lFMKXsgo4P6JcN68Q4SXC4PpOEJk4SqHMglEO0Qw7pUytHJaeVGAJyKs5VOFVq6lSzl9XOzkC7IHaq3cgghuouPLgNDA1iVLGlGq3caDcZpzQWowJaPdVpd2kD3RQfddp6GHqYUeNhx7wEutPVIt1CRmAXl9JeK9H6A3QEfRG2QD57zKXDF%2BZMkZ5Kxl0PeV8BBn0mAUO%2BYwH4X3vjfNpr9yYf0putXxtM672UAcAlyrMuYsAUAoq4qj%2BZmHgULKwJ1kH4FQegzB2D3ZbIIUw9SastInH5icM55yLnnP/mbCZ9D3KeQOareyOTBHM2EY8hYDVkrfUkEAA%3D).  (Clang is similar):

```
# GCC11 -O3  with C++ name demangling
func_1():
        mov     DWORD PTR sink[rip], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR sink2[rip], 2
        ret
func_2(void (*)()) [clone .constprop.0]:
        mov     DWORD PTR sink[rip], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR sink2[rip], 2
        ret
main:
      # note no arg passed, calling a special version of the function
      # specialized for function = func_1
        call    func_2(void (*)()) [clone .constprop.0]
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Of course if we hadn't disabled inlining of func_2, main would just `call func_1`.  Or inline that body of `func_1` into main and not do any calls.

---

MSVC might not be willing to do that "optimization", instead preferring to just inline `func_2` into `main` as `call func_1`.

If you want to force it to make clunky asm that duplicates `func_1` unnecessarily, **you could use a template to do the same thing as constprop**, taking the function pointer as a template arg, so you can instantiate `func_2<func1>` as a stand-alone non-inline function if you really want.  (Perhaps with `_declspec(noinline)`).

Your `func_2` can accept `func_1` as an unused argument if you want.

```
using pFunc = void(*)();
int sink, sink2;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define NOINLINE _declspec(noinline)
#define ALWAYS_INLINE  /* */
#else
#define NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline)) // not noclone or noipa, we *want* those to happen
#define ALWAYS_INLINE  __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif

//ALWAYS_INLINE // Seems not needed for this case, with the template version
void func_1() { sink = 1; sink2 = 2; }

template <pFunc f>
NOINLINE void func_2() {  f(); }

int main()
{
   func_2<func_1>();
}
```

##### Compiles as desired with MSVC -O2 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/hqkAA6oCoRODB7evv5JKWkCIWGRLDFxZgl2mA7pQgRMxASZPn5ctpj2jgK19QSFEdGxegp1DU3ZrcM9fcWlEgCUtqhexMjsHF6pRgDUiQBiXgzIWyYAzAAiWwBuqHjoEABUcxBzp1YaAIKhBFubANakP1CvzMrxMH3MJzwVCwVC2AH0ALJCNxwgBq2AASmD3hCYaFMFtwgB5ACS4SCZOw8KwyFoCkSVQgDBuDFo%2BJe4LMJzxYS27yCAHV3gBNIRwskU8JUrYAenuW3uMuxEPaSmVXJ5BOJEsp8LhTAIBGIeCiXgImDhcKgzNCbLCczmsplW2Z32ZtIEBJILpuiSYAIA7gT7gHDAR5QQECkCUQtggmIkGQx1dzMDRefyhaLxeTdXqDUaTWaLVaIGJQwBPBRw23sjk4rmuKHKj4ymWZkVinVSp1bISYTAsBQ%2Bt0DrDoLb8YhbSN4YeiJSBwgIGcIGODxIGc1XWKpATY663ScHZBwrjPY4AdgsgIYv2O5y2XFet%2BBD4uIJON5Ml7OLfe5osJuBoEqcbh7Cek6nNg2LarmPaHhOVAnnCZgXj%2BN6Ts8L4/n%2B4IfF8WwsEwoTYeC17YlsVHIYcqFgTRp7Pic2DYV%2Byq/hwCy0JwACsvB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1g/EsKygVyPCkAQmicQsvwgCckgAHRcJeACcPE8ScZgAGySIZGiSAAHK03EcJI/GKcJnC8AoIAJApgmcaQcCwDAiAoKgQF0LE5CUGgAX0HEwBcFwJx8HQ5rEM5EBRPZUShPUFacHJoVsIIRKshl7mkFgxFGOIhX4MQVSOJcmDOYVmCqFUxaZbwXztPZbJRMQ6UeFg9mFiwLULFQBjAAoqJ4JgAZEkmLUyIIIhiOwUjzfIShqPZugBAYRgoOJlj6CazmQAsqCJJ0DB1QAtESJxbFdNB%2BldyCJE57RVekLgMO4njNHowT4jMgytMkqQXWMLS5GD6TTAMcQTO91RdCMjS/eMbQdDUKOwyUwO2CjENDNjgNw/MizLKsehGgOQ36LxdmFSJHCqOZhlXcZWzAMgRxRepd0QGJljWACuCEN6EKtFsHhhbExxcmYcy8G5WgOqQKkGepFmXlFakaOUhlcKzdM2bwg08QkAlCUzTkufJikLF5vmhYkgVkBQEDO67KA7ZFkgaAkNC0PFiXJYVqXMMQBVZf5OUEHltAFUJxWGMAZVJ3glXVDVdVCQ1TXmnNbXWUJnXdZHvVrEJA20yNTBjRNU0zYwc38AtojiCtrdrSo6iFboMU%2B3tQsHZ1x3PMJ53pNdt1vZjzgQK4hOtADRSkyDeTg2jkOg/kDA47MCNzww3SjFvQyIxdJ%2B9CTuPw/jPRL/fDT78DCwKFJlOtNTaw8Fx9OkJbXgTMWZsw5rSFOT4NIaHUhoLYAt9o2C2KLIg04JYAmli7cKcsTgnEVnbdyqs1xMCwHEce1lbKkDNhbey1tbC22VkpNWqkzCa3MtraKft9aG0MsbE4DMraOXwSrTyPkIBIE9uFYKHt/KYMGJcF6iQ4SXC4NpOEBk4SqGMrFIOu5KChyEuHdKc1sqMDjvleyydSqV14BVD62d7J52QM1bgrVBDtRcYdLqPUMDWPksaQaLjhqjXGpNaas0PFd0Wh3aQXdFA902noQephh42FHvAU6k8BDTzMLPD689F5n2Xt9F%2Bd8d6byyNvDeMMb4Hwxnk4%2BBNCl1KRg0qYNS8aTFPhUombTV63zJu/Cmy0/E00CcbPiACaGcE0ZIIiCh5FXBUXzMwcDBZWAOkg/AKDsGSwwa7HZeCGGq3VicPmODzkXIucbChgCHIcBtq5e2f8OA5MmYzQRRyFg1QSp9SQQA)), and GCC/clang

```
int sink DD   01H DUP (?)                     ; sink
int sink2 DD  01H DUP (?)               ; sink2

void func_2<&void func_1(void)>(void) PROC              ; func_2<&func_1>, COMDAT
        mov     DWORD PTR int sink, 1             ; sink
        mov     DWORD PTR int sink2, 2      ; sink2
        ret     0
void func_2<&void func_1(void)>(void) ENDP              ; func_2<&func_1>

void func_1(void) PROC                           ; func_1, COMDAT
        mov     DWORD PTR int sink, 1             ; sink
        mov     DWORD PTR int sink2, 2      ; sink2
        ret     0
void func_1(void) ENDP                           ; func_1

main    PROC                                            ; COMDAT
$LN4:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        call    void func_2<&void func_1(void)>(void)       ; func_2<&func_1>
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

Note the duplicated bodies of func_1 and func_2.

**You should check (with a disassembler) that the linker doesn't do identical code folding** and just attach the both symbol names to one block of machine code.

---

I don't think this looks like much of an obfuscation technique; IDK why having a 2nd copy of a function with identical machine code would be a problem to reverse engineer.  I guess it would maybe create more overall work, and people wouldn't notice that two calls to different functions are actually doing the same thing.

I mostly answered as an exercise in making a compiler spit out the asm I wanted it to, whether or not that has value to anyone else.

Obviously it only works for compile-time-constant function pointers; commenters have been discussing self-modifying code and scripting languages. If you wanted this for non-const function pointer args to `func_1`, you're completely out of luck in a language like C++ that's designed for strictly ahead-of-time compilation.